# Download .exe from MediaFire

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a project in VB, it has a files downloader, it works fine with files like .txt or images but when I try to download an .exe, the .exe turns to corrupted file.

I'm using this code:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.mediafire.com/file/w9lk3emdczlb8hi/x_y_w_h.exe", "C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\Desktop\x_y_w_h.exe")

Process.Start("C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\Desktop\x_y_w_h.exe")
```

Downloads the .exe from the mediafire and sets the Location path and after it it opens it with Process.Start but the .exe is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
Dim savePath As String = "your_save_path" 'Remember to include the file_name.extension_name at the end of the save path
Dim WebClientDownload As New WebClient
WebClientDownload.DownloadFile("http://download1917.mediafire.com/breo3h1b14og/w9lk3emdczlb8hi/x_y_w_h.exe", savePath)
MsgBox("Download Complete.")
```

---

***Remarks:***

I had this problem in the past. You were trying to save the html web page as a `.exe` file as said by @DavidWilson.

---

To solve this, you have to **find** the ***direct download link***, in this case, I **right-clicked** on the **download button** and then clicked on "**copy link address**". It's always a good idea to test if the link copied is functioning (some file hosting sites invoke a script to start the download, but mediafire isn't that tricky)